# Symfony2 Doctrine ORM Manager named "customer" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hello I coopied the example for using two different database connections from the Symfony2 documentation: [Symfony2 multiple connections documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)
So however Symfony does not find the the costumer entity manager.
(The parameters are defined properly)

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
        customer:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host2%"
            port:     "%database_port2%"
            dbname:   "%database_name2%"
            user:     "%database_user2%"
            password: "%database_password2%"
            charset:  UTF8

orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AppBundle:  ~
        customer:
            connection: customer
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
```

The Controller looks like this:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

    // Both of these return the "customer" entity manager
    $customerEm = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('customer');
    $customerEm = $this->get('doctrine.orm.customer_entity_manager');
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
    ));
}
```

I should get the costumer entity manager, but however Symfony throws an invalid argument exception with the message.

```
[2015-10-19 23:19:18] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception 
InvalidArgumentException: "Doctrine ORM Manager named "customer" does 
not exist." at /srv/www/htdocs/symfony/my_project_name/app/cache
/prod/classes.php line 7344 {"exception":"[object] 
(InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Doctrine ORM Manager named 
\"customer\" does not exist. at /srv/www/htdocs/symfony/my_project_name
/app/cache/prod/classes.php:7344)"} []
```

I cleaned the cache with php app/console cache:clear but this does not help.

Comment: `cache:clear` clears the `dev` environment by default, but looking at your error log, you receive the error in your `prod` environment. To clear the cache on your production environment, add `-e prod` flag, like this `cache:clear -e prod` and refresh your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artamiel had the right answer in a comment:

[Symfony2 Doctrine ORM Manager named "customer" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225670/symfony2-doctrine-orm-manager-named-customer-does-not-exist/33229224#comment54257105_33225670)

> cache:clear clears the dev environment by default, but looking at your error log, you receive the error in your prod environment. To clear the cache on your production environment, add -e prod flag, like this cache:clear -e prod and refresh your page.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think, one declaration of entity manager in your controller is enough:

```
/ *** /   
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');

    $customerEm = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('customer');

    / *** /
}
```

Second, are you sure that you can declare the same bundle in your mapping configuration (`AppBundle: ~` in this case) ?